# Can I replace a control with another control in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, replace, controls

Is there any way to replace one control with another?
I have a library from a vendor that uses a TextBox and I would like to change it to a RichTextBox.
Can I maybe set up a Style with a TargetType=TextBox and assign it to RichTextBox?
I do have access to the vendor code, but putting the replacement in the parents Resources would be much easier than updating their code each time they have a new release.
Is this even possible?
Thanks!

Comment: You could override the control template providing the textbox with your own. Would need to know more about the vendor stuff though.

Comment: I'm going to have to go thru their source code. Setting a control template does nothing. I'm guessing they are setting it directly in their code before I can get control of it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the control(s) in question, I would recommend using the "Edit Template > Edit a copy" in VS or Blend and changing the TextBox to a RichTextBox. This should leave the rest of the template intact.

If that doesn't work, please post the ControlTemplate and/or Style code you used, and maybe a screenshot of the vendor control.